# git push error: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Permission denied

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, centos

I'm on CentOS 7 and trying to push to github. First I was using ssh, but my system seems to have some weird bug where my ssh keys keep disappearing (I know that's unbelievable, but I have no other explanation.) Instead, I've been trying to use https, but I'm unable to push to github and don't know why. Here's what happens:

```
$ git push origin remote
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Permission denied
```

Can you help?

Comment: ok, there's no bug known to mankind where SSH keys just disappear. These are regular, owner-only readable files ~/.ssh, so figure out what happened to these files. Are all files in that folder really owned by your user? `ls -lh ~/.ssh` might help.
My wild guess is that since you see spurious things happen in the most intimate parts of your home folder, you really should fix that first, before moving on fixing permissions for git username storage. Are you doing SSH oder git things as root, where you shouldn't?!

Comment: It's not really a bug—I'm relatively new to linux, and I'm not quite sure which files persist through reboot and which don't. I'm also sharing the system with other users, and perhaps one of them overwrote my .ssh directory accident. I definitely don't know what happened, but I think https might be easier than ssh in this case.

Comment: If you're not using the same username as the others (*never* do that), then they won't be able to write on any of your files; in fact, they won't be able to *read* your ~/.ssh directory.

Comment: well...they have root access. this is just for a class project.

Comment: Who in the world with root powers would mess with you .ssh folder? There's so much evil out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was definitely that the version of `git` I was using had a bug.

Separately, I and my group partners are much more familiar with `Linux` now, and we recognize that using the same `.ssh` folder (as `root`, no less!) for all of our keys was a bad idea.

In any case, we eventually stopped mucking around with the server (since we really didn't know what we were doing) and deployed our website with `Heroku` instead. But thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use https, you need the full url of your repo:

```
git remote set-url https://<yourLogin>@github.com/<yourLogin>/<yourRepo>
```

Then you can try a `git push`.
That will ask you for your GitHub account password, unless you have activated the 2FA (See "[About Two-Factor Authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/)"), in which case you would need to generate first a [PAT (Personnal Acces Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/).

Comment: I don't have 2FA activated (yet.) So I did what you said, and now when I enter
`$ git push -u origin master` I get:
`fatal: could not read Password for 'https://mchenja@github.com':  Permission denied`

Comment: @mchenja what version of git are you using (it could be a bug: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/Git+clone+error+-+could+not+read+Password)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried, and the only way I could produce something similar was by disowning parts of my `.git` files. Given the fact that SSH credentials, as you say, 'disappear', I'd guess this is actually what the error message says:

```
fatal: could not read Password
```

i.e., you don't have read access to the file you're trying to read.

Now, the hunt is on for files in your home directory that are *not* readable by you:

```
cd
find -not -readable -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh
```

Will give you details about all files that your user can't read that are in your home directory. Typically, you should only see a few lock files there. I suspect you have something in a .ssh folder, too, or in your git repositories.